# How to prevent dropping public schema in Heroku PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, flyway

Luckily I was still in pretty early development mode.

I wanted to update my schema using some FlywayDB magic by just dropping and re-creating the `public` schema on my local development database, but I wasn't paying attention and I had the Heroku one open in PgAdmin as well! Well, I dropped the one for Heroku (the one that will become the "production" database once the application has some users), and it freaked me out, so here I am.

I would like some kind of safety from myself to keep me from dropping this without using the Heroku Toolbox, but I'm not sure if that's possible. All the `drop schema` prevention things I've seen by Googling require me to have admin rights, which I obviously don't have in a shared environment like Heroku.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm using Flyway too and added what I consider a bit of a safety net by adding a Flyway user to each database, setting that up out-with Flyway and granting the user the required privileges. Using such an approach, perhaps you could add such a user to each of your databases but limit the Flyway user on Heroku, so it can't drop things. I'm not familiar with Heroku but thought I'd share, in case the idea helps something come to mind.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm not sure that's an option in Heroku, but I'll certainly check into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about preventing `drop`, but if you take regular backups with [Heroku PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) you can easily [import a backup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) if something bad happens.

**EDIT**

Here's some documentation on the [default role and its limitations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permission).

Comment: That's awesome! I actually had been looking in the dashboard to try and figure out how to configure backup schedules and just assumed that it wasn't possible with the free tier of PG. This was a great help and a daily backup will do the trick. Thanks!